# LINQ select selects only 1 item even when there are more items

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Linq statement that has to check which Client is connected to which user

```
     public List<Client_Dto> GetClientByBehandelaar(string loggedInUserId)
    {
        try
        {
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32(loggedInUserId);
            nestorDBDataContext db = new nestorDBDataContext();
            var result =
                (from relaties in db.tbl_Relaties
                 where relaties.ID_Persoon == userID
                 select new Client_Dto()
                 {
                     ID = relaties.NestorNrCliënt
                 }).ToList();
            List<Client_Dto> clienten = result;
            return clienten;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("GetClientByBehandelaar Failed " + e);
        }
    }
```

but it only selects one even when there are 87 more in the DB with the same userID. I've been staring myself to death on this one .. Can someone help

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like? What does your schema look like for that property?

Comment: @Nicolas are you perhaps querying the wrong field and/or table? I think your probably querying the master table rather than the foreign key table (hence why your only ever getting back a single result). Also there is no need for you to do `List<Client_Dto> clienten = result; return clienten;` just return result.

Comment: Another suggestion on hygiene as well. Dispose of your `db` when you're done, or put the entire construct into a `using` scope statement.

Comment: @J.Steen I was going to suggest that, however, contexts are very lightweight therefore it's not really *that* big a deal. I guess for consistency and just general housekeeping it's still a good idea.

Comment: @James Which is why I used the word hygiene, not necessity. =D Besides - it's good to learn such things early so you don't get bitten in the ass at a later date, in a larger and more critical scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it here and your code works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Relatie
    {
        public Int32 ID_Persoon { get; set; }
        public Int32 NestorNrCliënt { get; set; }

        public Relatie(int ID_Persoon, int NestorNrCliënt)
        {
            this.ID_Persoon = ID_Persoon;
            this.NestorNrCliënt = NestorNrCliënt;
        }
    }

    class nestorDBDataContext
    {
        public List<Relatie> tbl_Relaties = new List<Relatie> {
            new Relatie(15, 27),
            new Relatie(15, 28),
            new Relatie(15, 29),
            new Relatie(15, 30),
            new Relatie(14, 30),
            new Relatie(14, 30),
            new Relatie(14, 30),
        };
    }

    class Program
    {
        public struct Client_Dto{
            public Int32 ID;
        }

        public static List<Client_Dto> GetClientByBehandelaar(string loggedInUserId)
        {
            try
            {
                int userID = Convert.ToInt32(loggedInUserId);
                nestorDBDataContext db = new nestorDBDataContext();
                var result =
                    (from relaties in db.tbl_Relaties
                     where relaties.ID_Persoon == userID
                     select new Client_Dto()
                     {
                         ID = relaties.NestorNrCliënt
                     }).ToList();
                List<Client_Dto> clienten = result;
                return clienten;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("GetClientByBehandelaar Failed " + e);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetClientByBehandelaar("15").Count());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe you need to look at this boolean comarison `ID_Persoon == userID`

Use Debug.WriteLine to output the results for you.

Comment: You're making assumptions about `tbl_Relaties` that might not be true. Are you sure that's what the OPs data structure and data content looks like? =)

Comment: Absolutely not, i am assuming everything i dont know to be able to test anything... the linq is tested and its ok - the error is somewhere other than in that portion of the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Client_Dto> GetClientByBehandelaar(string loggedInUserId)
    {
        try
        {
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32(loggedInUserId);
            List<Client_Dto> result = new List<Client_Dto>();
            using (nestorDBDataContext db = new nestorDBDataContext())
            {
                IEnumerable<Client_Dto> client_dto =
                    (from relaties in db.tbl_Relaties
                     where relaties.ID_Persoon == userID
                     select relaties);
                result = client_dto.ToList();
                return result;
            }                               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("GetClientByBehandelaar Failed " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP is already doing? Except you're also creating an instance of a list you're not even using. Though I'll commend that you're actually using `using`.

Comment: What instance of which list not using?

Comment: `List<Client_Dto> result = new List<Client_Dto>();` <- You're simply discarding this instantiated list, replacing it with the `client_dto.ToList();`. And, to be brutally precise, you're not returning the result from the method anywhere. This wouldn't compile. ;)

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(loggedInUserId);
        nestorDBDataContext db = new nestorDBDataContext();
        List<Client_Dto> clienten =
            (from relaties in db.tbl_Relaties
             where relaties.ID_Persoon.Equals(userID)
             select relaties
             ).ToList();
        return clienten;
```

maybe it work.